# Executing SSIS package on SQL server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, ssis-2005

I am working on upgrading legacy applications that used DTS packages. This is the first time working with SSIS packages.

The application (which lives in various places) will need to invoke and execute an SSIS package that is on a SQL 2005 server. So relative path do not work for me since someone in New York would need to access the same Server via the application and get the same results back. We are also keeping a log of everything that happens throughout the transaction. The only option left is to create a stored procedure and get the stored procedure to kick off the SSIS package but I feel as though we may lose logging capabilities then. How do I execute the SSIS package remotely using C#.net?

I've already looked at the Microsoft solutions of execution and they don't work in my instance. Doing a SQL Server Agent schedule is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to create a stored procedure to run ssis packages, and you will not lose logging capabilities because you can get all outputs sent by the package.

The following links contains example on executing packages from sql server and from external files using stored procedure:

- [Executing a SSIS Package from Stored Procedure in SQL Server](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/executing-a-ssis-package-from-stored-procedure-in-sql-server.html)
- [How to Call SSIS Package from the Stored Procedure](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27156/How-to-Call-SSIS-Package-from-the-Stored-Procedure)